# C++, Running two functions in parallel and collaborative way

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, collaborative

I have two methods that I want to execute in parallel, data are passed by const reference.

As soon as one of the method has finished its job, it is not necessary for the other to continue, since one of them can have a long execution time depending the entry and therefore must stop.

I found that I could execute the two methods in parallel by running two threads using the `<thread>` header, but i had to wait for both methods to finish after joining them.

How can i achieve this type of parallel processing with such a collaborative mecanisme ?.

Comment: Do you mean **without** such mechanisms?

Comment: no, with this mechanism.

Comment: "but I must wait for both methods to finish" and "it is not necessary for the other to continue" sounds contradictory to me

Comment: yeah this sounds misleading sorry, I just mentioned that I tried to use threads but I had to wait the two  methods finish their execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a small sample to show how it is done. It is not archivable with join, as you already found out. You need an event you can signal from a thread, when it has the result. For that, you have to use `std::conditon_variable`. The sample shows the minimal possible solution for your described problem. In the sample, the result is a simple in.

There are two pitfalls you have to care.

a.The thread is finished before the main is waiting for. For that reason I lock the mutex **before** I start the threads.

b. The result is overwritten. I managed that by testing the result before writing it.

```
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;

int result = -1;

void thread1()
{
    // Do something
    // ....
    // ....

    // got a result? publish it!
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    if (result != -1)
        return; // there is already a result!

    result = 0; // my result
    cv.notify_one(); // say I am ready
}

void thread2()
{
    // Do something else
    // ....
    // ....

    // got a result? publish it!
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    if (result != -1)
        return; // there is already a result!

    result = 1; // my result
    cv.notify_one(); // say I am ready
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx); // needed so the threads cannot finish befor wait
    std::thread t1(thread1), t2(thread2);

    cv.wait(lck); // wait until one result

    // here result is 0 or 1;

    // If you use the loop described below, you can use join safely:
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    // You have to call join or detach of std::thread objects before the
    // destructor of std::thread is called. 

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to stop the other thread if one has already a result, the only legit way is to test the result frequently in both threads an stop if someone already has the result. In this case, if you use a pointer or or generic type, you should mark it with the `volatile` modifier.
Here how the thread function may look if you have to do work in a loop:

```
void thread1()
{
    // Do something
    bool bFinished=false;
    while(!bFinished)
    {
      { // this bracket is necessary to lock only the result test. Otherwise you got a deadlock a forced sync situation.
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        if (result != -1)
           return; // there is already a result!
      }         
      // do what ever you have to do
    }

    // got a result? publish it!
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    if (result != -1)
        return; // there is already a result!

    result = 0; // my result
    cv.notify_one(); // say I am ready
}
```

Comment: i understood the event mechanism you done with `std::condition_variable`, as soon as a method call `cv.notify_one()` the `cv.wait`breaks right?. As i'm new to thread and multithreading programming, i tried your solution and i get error "abort() has been called" ?

Comment: @Vutz I was a little lazy. A thread must be joined or detached before the std::thread object got out of scope. Otherwise your abort happened. Seems you using VS2013 :-) I updated my code.

Comment: effectively that worked well =), another point, you set extra curly braces in the while loop to prevent some problems , do you have any good introductory resource to tackle these concepts of programming plz? (deadlock, mutex, ...).

Comment: @Vutz You ask another question as comment. Please open that as new question as your first question is already answered.